# Script to calculate a total and then merge cells into one in column 'c' if column 'a' has the same date (Using for timesheet)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-apps

Column A = Date (so there could be multiple rows for the same day but different times)
Column B = Time spent (number)
Column C = Will be the total of all cells in column 'B' if has the same date in column 'A'

So I'm looking to automatically merge the cells in column C if the date is the same in column 'A' so I have one merged cell with the day total hours using a Google Apps script

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't think you need apps script here, formula is suffice already.

Comment: Thanks @KinSiang - This final output of the timesheet will be mostly automated, so my example is just a basic version to try easily explain what I'm trying to achieve, I've put the details in my response to GoranK - But I'm trying to find a way that the total will always be in the same row as the last row for that particular day, there could be multiple sessions within one day so no static range - hope this makes sense, it's quite tricky to explain

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend merging cells. It is doable, but you must use a script.
Here is a solution with a simple formula:

```
=QUERY( {arrayformula(int(A2:A)),B2:B},"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label Col1 'Date', sum(Col2) 'Total hours'",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @GoranK - The example I've given is just a really basic sheet to easily show what I'm trying to achieve, so I'm looking to get the total hours to always be shown within the final row for that particular day - so in your screenshot Value of E2 to be shown in cell E6 - so to somehow recognise that the previous cell is the same 'date' so the total value must be applied to the last row of this date range, this is because I'll have a script to automatically hide rows, so the value needs to be alongside the latest row - if this makes sense?